# List Manipulation Question

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list consisting of strings and integers:

```
testList = {a, Abc, b, 3, a, c, d, b, Abc, m, n, 2, q, r, w, Def, q, 3, a, Def, 1, a, g};
```

and I would like to obtain the following sublists:

```
desiredResult = {{Abc, 3, a, c, d, b}, {Abc, 2, q, r, w}, {Def, 3, a},  ={Def, 1, a, g}}
```

This involves eliminating everything before the first instance of the "Abc" string, picking the "Abc" string, omitting anything between it and the next integer, and adding everything following this integer until the next instance of "Abc" etc. I think it's easier to look at the example than to describe it in words.  I'm not sure how to use pattern matching for this, any ideas would be gratefully received.

Comment: This should be a job for `SequenceCases`, but I don't have *Mathematica* 10.1 (only 10.0), so I can't test it.

Comment: The OP mentions that the data has Strings such as "Abc" etc. The edits and the answers over the years have made this page difficult to follow due to two parallel strains of input. The title is not particularly informative either.

Answer (score 9):

```
SequenceCases[
  testList
, { head : Abc | Def, Except[_Integer] ..., rest : Except[Abc | Def] ..
  } :> {head, rest}
]
```

Comment: This is great ... +1

Comment: @mrz thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
testList = {"a", "Abc", "b", 3, "a", "c", "d", "b",
   "Abc", "m", "n", 2, "q", "r", "w", "Def", "q",
   3, "a", "Def", 1, "a", "g"};

Apply[Join, {#1, #2 //. {a_String, b___} :> {b}} & @@@ 
  Rest@Partition[SplitBy[Join[{"Abc", 1},
      testList], # == "Abc" || # == "Def" &], 2], {1}]
```

> ```
> {{Abc, 3, a, c, d, b}, {Abc, 2, q, r, w}, {Def, 3, a}, {Def, 1, a, g}}
> ```

With trickier data.

```
testList = {"a", "Abc", "b", 3, "a", "c", "d", "b",
   "Abc", "Def", "Def", 1, "a", "g"};

Apply[Join, {#1, #2 //. {a_String, b___} :> {b}} & @@@   
   Rest@Partition[
     SplitBy[Join[{"Abc", 1}, testList /.
        {"Abc" -> Sequence[Null, "Abc"],
         "Def" -> Sequence[Null, "Def"]}],
      # === "Abc" || # === "Def" &], 2], {1}] /. Null -> Nothing
```

> ```
> {{Abc, 3, a, c, d, b}, {Abc}, {Def}, {Def, 1, a, g}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks will work on this more.

Answer (score 2):

In this code `q = 1` means "waiting for integer" and if not then `q = 0`.

```
ToExpression[Reap[Module[{n = 0, q = 0}, Sow[0, 0];
    Do[If[UpperCaseQ[#], Sow[i, ++n]; q = 1,
     If[q =!= 1, Sow[i, n], If[DigitQ[#], q = 0; Sow[i, n]]]] &[
      StringTake[i, 1]], {i, ToString /@ testList}]]][[2, 2 ;;]]]
```

> ```
> {{Abc, 3, a, c, d, b}, {Abc, 2, q, r, w}, {Def, 3, a}, {Def, 1, a, g}}
> ```

Comment: +1 Works with my trickier data too.

Answer (score 1):

My take on this is to deconstruct the list using replacement rules, generating a sort-of linked list along the way. It can likely be made more elegant, but here's what I came up with.

```
deconstruct[expr_List, vars_List] := Module[
  {lst, alts = Alternatives @@ vars},
  lst = testList /. {Shortest[___], a : alts, x___} :> {a, x};
  lst = lst //. {a : alts, Shortest[b___], c : alts, d___} :> {l[a, b], {c, d}} // Flatten;
  lst /. {Longest[a__l], b__} :> {a, l[b]} /. l -> List
 ]
```

Usages:

```
testList = {a, Abc, b, 3, a, c, d, b, Abc, m, n, 2, q, r, w, Def, q, 3, a, Def, 1, a, g};
deconstruct[testList, {Abc, Def}]
(* {{Abc, b, 3, a, c, d, b}, {Abc, m, n, 2, q, r, w}, {Def, q, 3, a}, {Def, 1, a, g}} *)
deconstruct[testList, {Abc}]
(* {{Abc, b, 3, a, c, d, b}, {Abc, m, n, 2, q, r, w, Def, q, 3, a, Def, 1, a, g}} *)
```

With Chris Degnen's trickier data:

```
testList = {"a", "Abc", "b", 3, "a", "c", "d", "b", "Abc", "Def", "Def", 1, "a", "g"};
deconstruct[testList, {Abc}]
(* {{"Abc", "b", 3, "a", "c", "d", "b"}, {"Abc"}, {"Def"}, {"Def", 1, "a", "g"}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = 
 {a, Abc, b, 3, a, c, d, b, Abc, m, n, 2, q, r, w, Def, q, 3, a, Def, 1, a, g};
```

We need to prepend the dummy `x` in case `list` starts with `Abc` or
`Def`

```
Rest @ Split[Prepend[x] @ list, StringLength[ToString @ #2] == 1 &] /.
 {a_, ___, b_Integer, c__} :> {a, b, c}
```

{{Abc, 3, a, c, d, b}, {Abc, 2, q, r, w}, {Def, 3, a}, {Def, 1, a, g}}