# Refinement of list manipulation question

Tags: list-manipulation

This question is related to [my previous post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/161035/125), but trickier I think:

Given:

```
testList = {Abc, d, e, 2, f, g, 1, h, Def, q, 2, j, k, 1, w, z, y}
```

Obtain:

```
desiredList = {{Abc, 2, f, g}, {Abc, 1, h}, {Def, 2, j, k}, {Def, 1, w, z, y}}
```

Here, we are putting "Abc" in front of each integer until "Def" is encountered, at which point *it* is inserted before each succeeding integer...

Comment: When you mention a question is a refinement of a previous question, you should provide a link to that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
org = Join @@ ((Function[{x}, Prepend[x, #[[1]]]] /@ {##2}) & @@@ #) &;
split = Split[Split[#, Not[IntegerQ[#2] || MemberQ[{Abc, Def}, #2]] &],
    Not[MemberQ[{Abc, Def}, #2[[1]]]] &] &;

org @ split @ testList
```

> {{Abc, 2, f, g}, {Abc, 1, h}, {Def, 2, j, k}, {Def, 1, w, z, y}}

Answer (score 4):

This code simply splits at the symbols and the integers, and joins the relevant parts.

```
splitAt[list_,pat_]:=Module[{pos=Flatten@Position[list,pat]},MapThread[list[[#1;;#2]]&,{pos,Append[Rest@pos-1,-1]}]];
Flatten[Function[u,Prepend[#,First@u]&/@splitAt[u,_Integer]]/@splitAt[testList,_?(#==Abc||#==Def&)],1]
(*{{Abc, 2, f, g}, {Abc, 1, h}, {Def, 2, j, k}, {Def, 1, w, z, y}}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {Abc, d, e, 2, f, g, 1, h, Def, q, 2, j, k, 1, w, z, y};
```

Here's something more readable:

```
Join @@ SequenceCases[
  list
, { head : Abc | Def
  , Except[_Integer] ...
  , rest : Except[Abc | Def] ..
  } :> Flatten /@ Thread[{head, Split[{rest}, Not@IntegerQ[#2] &]}]
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following approach, which is going to *sequentially* build the output, by treating the entries in the input list in an *appropriate* way, depending on their position *relative* to flag `Def`.

(Please note that if you are interested in the code of this answer you can skip all the commenting and go straight to the end of this answer.)

First, we need to obtain the positions of the flag `Def` and the integers in the input list, respectively.

```
{{fpos}} = Position[list, Def]
ipos = Position[list, _Integer]
```

Evaluating the code above with our `testList` as input returns

> ```
> {{9}}
> {{4}, {7}, {11}, {14}}
> ```

(please note that `fpos` evaluates to `9`, not `{{9}}`).

Next, we are going to create two sub-lists of indexes, namely a sub-list with the indexes of integer entries in the input list that are located *before* the flag (in this list, we will include the position of the `Def` flag, too) and a sub-list of indexes of integer entries in the input list that are located *after* the flag.

```
pos1 = Cases[ipos, {n_} :> n /; n < fpos]
If[fpos - 1 > Last[pos1], pos1 = Flatten[{pos1, fpos}]]

pos2 = Cases[ipos, {n_} :> n /; n > fpos]
```

Evaluating this, yields

> ```
> {4, 7}
> {4, 7, 9}
> {11, 14}
> ```

(The second line in the code segment above, is used to identify the case where there are intervening symbols between the last integer before the `Def` flag and he flag itself-as is the case with the `testList` input list).

The following step, entails assembling the *core* of the output list out of the index lists `pos1` and `pos2`.

```
res11 = Apply[Take[list, Flatten[{##} + {0, -1}]] &, Partition[pos1, 2, 1], 1]

res21 = Apply[Take[list, Flatten[{##} + {0, -1}]] &, Partition[pos2, 2, 1], 1]
res22 = Drop[list, Last[pos2 - 1]]
```

Both `res11` and `res21` compose the core of the output sub-lists as does `res22`, which is introduced to tackle the last admissible integer entry in the input list; `Partition[<positions>,2,1]` supplies the input for `Take`ing the appropriate parts of the input list.

Evaluating the code, produces

> ```
> {{2, f, g}, {1, h}}
>
> {{2, j, k}}
> {1, w, z, y}
> ```

Essentially, the transformation of input to output is complete; the only thing left is to format the output sub-lists appropriately, namely to insert the `Abc` and `Def` markers as intended.

```
res1 = Apply[{Abc, ##} &, Flatten[{res11}, 1], 1]
res2 = Apply[{Def, ##} &, Flatten[{res21, {res22}}, 1], 1]

Flatten[{res1, res2}, 1]
```

Evaluation of this last segment of code returns

> ```
> {{Abc, 2, f, g}, {Abc, 1, h}}
>
> {{Def, 2, j, k}, {Def, 1, w, z, y}}
> ```

and, what is effectively the requested output

> ```
> {{Abc, 2, f, g}, {Abc, 1, h}, {Def, 2, j, k}, {Def, 1, w, z, y}}
> ```

Having said that-on a personal note-I have come to realize that when I need to resort to similar sequential treatment of output, it is highly likely that I could have reorganized my code in a different way, to begin with. It might not be the case here (obviously, I don't know) but I'm pretty sure that, at some level and to a certain extent, *Mathematica* / *Wolfram Language* can produce structured output with a lot less trouble.

---

All the code bundled in a `Module`:

```
f[list_] := Module[{fpos, ipos, pos1, pos2, res11, res21, res22, res1, res2},

  {{fpos}} = Position[list, Def];
  ipos = Position[list, _Integer];

  pos1 = Cases[ipos, {n_} :> n /; n < fpos]; 
  If[fpos - 1 > Last[pos1], pos1 = Flatten[{pos1, fpos}]];

  pos2 = Cases[ipos, {n_} :> n /; n > fpos];


  res11 = Apply[Take[list, Flatten[{##} + {0, -1}]] &, Partition[pos1, 2, 1],1];

  res21 = Apply[Take[list, Flatten[{##} + {0, -1}]] &, Partition[pos2, 2, 1],1]; 
  res22 = Drop[list, Last[pos2 - 1]];

  res1 = Apply[{Abc, ##} &, Flatten[{res11}, 1], 1];
  res2 = Apply[{Def, ##} &, Flatten[{res21, {res22}}, 1], 1];

  Flatten[{res1, res2}, 1]

]
```

and evaluating

> ```
> f[testList] == desiredList
> ```

should return `True`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanatory notes!  Would be interested in your thoughts of generalizing this for as many of the "Abc"-type strings that might be contained in this type of list, i.e. "Abc" , "Def" - our present example -, "Ghi", "Jkl" etc

Comment: It nice to know you find the notes helpful. Sure I'd be happy to give it a try, but I think it's only fair to everybody if you posted it as a new question; please note also that among the other answers there are some *really* elegant and efficient(-looking) implementations of a solution to your current problem that *seem* to require marginal modifications in order to address (both this and) your new problem

Comment: Thank you, I am getting to know the ways of the community a bit better, and understand your point; I will make a new post.

Answer (score 3):

```
ToExpression[Reap[Module[{n = 0, p, q = 0}, Sow[0, 0];
    Do[If[UpperCaseQ[#], p = i; q = 1,
       If[DigitQ[#], Sow[p, ++n]; q = 0];
       If[q =!= 1, Sow[i, n]]] &[StringTake[i, 1]],
             {i, ToString /@ testList}]]][[2, 2 ;;]]]
```

> ```
> {{Abc, 2, f, g}, {Abc, 1, h}, {Def, 2, j, k}, {Def, 1, w, z, y}}
> ```