# Generalization of list manipulation query

Tags: list-manipulation

The solutions for my earlier [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161052/refinement-of-list-manipulation-question) regarding list manipulation are really helpful. I'd like to generalize the question by having the list contain an arbitrary number of delimiters of the "class" "Abc".  The original problem had only two.

So, given:

```
newTestList = {z, Abc, d, e, 2, f, g, 1, h, Def, q, 2, j, k, 1, w, z, y, Ghi, 3, k, j}
```

obtain:

```
newDesiredList = {{Abc, 2, f, g}, {Abc, 1, h}, {Def, 2, j, k}, {Def, 1, w, z, y}, {Ghi, 3, k, j}}.
```

Comment: You can easily extend my `Abc | Def`. Other answers can be adapted too, have you tried?

Comment: Hi Kuba, thanks as always for your help.  I did add Ghi etc to your solution, and it worked well on my test data.  The actual data I'm working with has 4700+ elements, and applying your solution (if I'm doing it right), has not yet finished evaluating after waiting several minutes...

Comment: try `Alternatives @@ {Abc, Def, Ghi, Jkl, ...}`, but yes, my approach probably does not scale well. It might be a good idea to mention that there is 4700 tokens and how long your full list is.

Comment: The delimiters are strings, in this case, the names of months.  The same thing happens when I used your Alternatives@@ suggestion.

Comment: Downvoted. Something I rarely do. Reason: This is not a mechanical turk site. Your last 3 questions - all related to this - have been "Here's what I want, do it for me". You will likely never be self-sufficient in Mathematica with such a strategy.

Answer (score 1):

First one needs a pattern that will match only the delimiters, which is not completely trival.  I propose:

```
delimPatt = _Symbol?(
    Function[s, 
        (* Symbol name is of the form upper lower lower *)
        StringMatchQ[ToString@s, RegularExpression["[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]{2}"] ] 
        (* symbol name contains only consecutive letters *)
        && Union@Differences@LetterNumber@ToString@s == {1}
    ]
)
```

(This can likely be improved, but I found it to be fairly intuitive.)

As @Kuba stated in the comments, you can then replace `Abc | Def` in @Kuba's [answer to your previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161068/11035) with `delimPatt`.

Rather than copying @Kuba's answer, I will modify it a bit into a form I find to be slightly more intuitive:

```
SequenceCases[newTestList,
     {d : delimPatt, rest : (Except[delimPatt] ..)}
     :> SequenceCases[{rest},
           p : {_Integer, Except[_Integer] ...} :> Prepend[p, d]
        ]
] // Catenate
```

> ```
> {{Abc, 2, f, g}, {Abc, 1, h}, {Def, 2, j, k}, {Def, 1, w, z, y}, {Ghi, 3, k, j}}
> ```

```
SameQ[%, newDesiredList]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Thanks - the actual data set has names of months instead of Abc, Def, etc., so that the pattern definition you suggest above doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, after some thought several of the answers to the previous [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161052/refinement-of-list-manipulation-question) are extendable to more than two delimiters.  In particular, @kglr's solution is pretty fast:

`org = Join @@ ((Function[{x}, Prepend[x, #[[1]]]] /@ {##2}) & @@@ #) &;
split = Split[Split[#, Not[IntegerQ[#2] || MemberQ[{Abc, Def}, #2]] &],
    Not[MemberQ[{Abc, Def}, #2[[1]]]] &] &;`

Thanks to all who responded, this is an amazingly helpful resource.